# Linear Spaces or Vector Spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

Tags: functional-analysis

Why are we only interested in vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$? Is it because of the wide-ranging applications of such linear spaces in analysis or due to some special properties of these fields (like Cauchy-completeness)? Are we not restricting ourselves when we consider only such spaces?

Comment: Who are "we"?  $\ $

Comment: I have on several occasions found useful times to consider vectors in $\Bbb F_2^n$ (*i.e. all entries only $0$ or $1$ and where $1+1=0$*).  I seem to recall even a few exercises from one of my textbooks being written in a vector space over $\Bbb F_p$ as well... so, although it is *common* to see vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, it is by no means *exclusively* those two.

Comment: [Galois Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_geometry) in particular concerns itself primarily with finite vector spaces rather than vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we not restricting ourselves when we consider only such spaces?

Mathematicians always restrict themselves in one way or another. Usually, vector spaces are assumed to be over some field. Now, isn't "field" a restriction here? Of course it is, and the generalization for rings instead of fields is called a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)).

Now, when we only take fields into consideration, why are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ so interesting? Their Cauchy-completeness is indeed a reason, because it allows one to define norms on the vector space such that they also induce a Cauchy-complete metric. But there can be other reasons as well, for teaching purposes alone. In the first year of math studies, a field is one of the first abstract concepts the students encounter. What better example to give than something they already know? Of course, one could work with a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any prime $p$ and sometimes that is interesting, but the elements of the field are finite if the vector space is finite dimensional. A vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ would also be finite, but its elements can appear complicated and difficult to work with. This is why these examples are usually only noted as "example" and not worked with much more besides some exercises. The motivation of the topic comes from $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as well and my favorite application example is computer tomography, which relies heavily on numeric methods, which in turn rely heavily on real vector spaces and that they work how they work. Physics also likes those vector spaces. In addition, there are some theorems in linear algebra which work only because of some properties of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, or some questions only have a unique answer there.

Rest assured, there is a lot of research going on vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, it is just not "important enough" to fit into the main curriculum in detail at this point, because it is not too extensively needed in higher courses.